# Can HealthKit accept medication Data?

Tags: ios, healthkit

I've been searching for an answer to this, but I can't find any good leads. I made a medication app and want to be able to push medication data to the HealthKit app. Is this functionality available yet?

Comment: I don't believe so (but I'm not a HealthKit expert). Medication data sounds like an `HKQuantitySample` but there's no corresponding Type Identifier for medicines (there would need to be a `custom` Type Identifier as there are so many drugs). Regardless, you'll need to check the documentation and raise an enhancement request if you think there's something missing: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/HealthKit/Reference/HealthKit_Framework/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014707

Comment: I've looked into the documentation, didn't find anything. I've got a hunch that healthkit doesn't support medication. Maybe it's just too new. Thanks!

Comment: 2022 / iOS 16 Update: The iOS Health app now has the support for medications, but the API is not yet available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no support for medications in HealthKit.  You should [file a bug](http://bugreporter.apple.com) with Apple if you'd like to see it added, though!